# Can't create wsdl based proxy from https (tlsv1.2) wsdl uri

Tags: web-services, tomcat, soap, wsdl, wso2-esb

I am trying to create a WSDL based proxy from a service. This service is running in a tomcat server that has been configured to accept only secured connections using TLSv1.2. And this service is outside the intranet where is wso2server running.

The problem appears when I test the wsdl uri in the WSDL based proxy template, launching the system the following alert: "Invalid WSDL URI (Unable to establish a connection)".
I have to say that the wso2esb has connection to outside and the problem isn't accessing to this url, because:

- If I accept no SSL connections on service's server, it works well.
- I can request the WSDL information using wget command to the https wsdl url
- I can create other proxies using secured connections, for example a proxy server from: https://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/AWSECommerceService.wsdl

According to browser connection information to the secured wsdl URL that failed, I get that the connection TLS protocol is 1.2 and the cipher is: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256

More useful information:

- wso2server version: 4.8.1
- java versions tested (failed in both): 1.7.0_45 and 1.8.0_60
- Added parameter in CARBON_HOME/bin/wso2server.sh: -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2
- Tomcat connector configuration from `CARBON_HOME/repository/conf/tomcat  /catalina-server.xml:`

  ```
  <Connector  protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
  port="8888"
  bindOnInit="false"
  sslProtocol="TLS"
  sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2"
  maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
  acceptorThreadCount="2"
  maxThreads="250"
  minSpareThreads="50"
  disableUploadTimeout="false"
  enableLookups="false"
  connectionUploadTimeout="120000"
  maxKeepAliveRequests="200"
  acceptCount="200"
  server="WSO2 Carbon Server"
  clientAuth="false"
  compression="on"
  scheme="https"
  secure="true"
  SSLEnabled="true"
  compressionMinSize="2048"
  noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata"
  compressableMimeType="..."
  URIEncoding="UTF-8" />
  ```
- Added in axis2.xml transport sender and receiver the following parameter:
  TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2

Maybe I have missed something in wso2server configuration?

---

Updated problem:

After installing the public part of the SSL certificate into ESB trust-store, I could create a proxy service based on the published WSDL without any problems and I can request the WSDL template through the ESB. But the problem I think it isn't solved completely:

Trying the service using SoapUI I get the following exception in the server (read in wso2carbon.log):

```
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-10-15 08:24:31,057] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.TargetHandler} -  I/O error: Received fatal alert: protocol_version {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.TargetHandler}
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1619)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1587)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.recvAlert(SSLEngineImpl.java:1756)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:1060)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:884)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:758)
at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:624)
at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.doUnwrap(SSLIOSession.java:228)
at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.doHandshake(SSLIOSession.java:263)
at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.isAppInputReady(SSLIOSession.java:380)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.inputReady(AbstractIODispatch.java:118)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.readable(BaseIOReactor.java:160)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:342)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:320)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:280)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:106)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:604)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-10-15 08:25:04,600]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.SourceHandler} -  Connection time out after request is read: http-incoming-11 {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.SourceHandler}
```

Maybe I misses something in axis2.xml configuration file ($CARBON_HOME/repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml)?. Here is the part related to:

- TransportReceiver (https part):

```
 
    <transportReceiver name="https" class="org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSSLListener">
        <parameter name="port" locked="false">8443</parameter>
        <parameter name="non-blocking" locked="false">true</parameter>
        <parameter name="bind-address" locked="false">XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX</parameter>
        <parameter name="WSDLEPRPrefix" locked="false">https://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8443</parameter>
        <parameter name="httpGetProcessor" locked="false">org.wso2.carbon.transport.nhttp.api.PassThroughNHttpGetProcessor
        <parameter name="HttpsProtocols">TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2</parameter>
        <parameter name="keystore" locked="false">
            <KeyStore>
                <Location>repository/resources/security/wso2carbon.jks</Location>
                <Type>JKS</Type>
                <Password>XXX</Password>
                <KeyPassword>XXX</KeyPassword>
            </KeyStore>
        </parameter>
        <parameter name="truststore" locked="false">
            <TrustStore>
                <Location>repository/resources/security/client-truststore.jks</Location>
                <Type>JKS</Type>
                <Password>XXX</Password>
            </TrustStore>
        </parameter>
   </transportReceiver>
```

- TransportSender (https part):

```
 
    <transportSender name="https" class="org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSSLSender">
        <parameter name="non-blocking" locked="false">true
        <parameter name="HttpsProtocols">TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2
        <parameter name="keystore" locked="false">
            <KeyStore>
                <Location>repository/resources/security/wso2carbon.jks</Location>
                <Type>JKS</Type>
                <Password>XXXX</Password>
                <KeyPassword>XXXX</KeyPassword>
            </KeyStore>
        </parameter>
        <parameter name="truststore" locked="false">
            <TrustStore>
                <Location>repository/resources/security/client-truststore.jks</Location>
                <Type>JKS</Type>
                <Password>XXXXX</Password>
            </TrustStore>
        </parameter>
        <parameter name="HostnameVerifier">AllowAll</parameter>        
    </transportSender>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you imported the public certificate of the service to the ESB's trust-store? If not, [This blog post](http://blog.facilelogin.com/2011/02/wso2-esb-invoking-web-service-via-https.html) may provide some idea (it's bit outdated though).

Comment: Thanks @Rajeev, that was a part of the problem. I though I had imported the public part of the SSL certificate into the ESB trust-store but it seemed that not. After doing that I could create an WSDL based proxy service without any problems (in other words I can access to the published wsdl through the ESB).

Answer (score 0):

The error "Unable to establish a connection" is just too unclear.

Start your server with SSL debug option (add  -Djavax.net.debug=all  to wso2server.sh).

This will produce a lot of output, but it helps you pinpoint the problem.